# Default language for Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, language, microsoft-word-365

I am using Word on two different PC with one of them running in Hungarian, and the other runs in English. What I have noticed, is that a Word file that is created in the Hungarian Word, will always assumes that the document is in Hungarian, regardless that it doesn't even contain a single Hungarian word. I even tried to select all text and then change the proofing language to English, but when I change a selected range of text to another style, it will change the proofing language back to Hungarian. The current input language does not affect this behavior as that only considers the language when you start typing, not when you change the language.

I could go through all the styles I potentially could use to set the proofing language as English, but the principal, that it retains the language together, with the default styles not having any proofing language set, bothers me. This means that I must change all styles every time I create a new document to have these style the proper language or change the language of Word before creating the document just to make sure this language is set to the desired language instead.

I uncompressed the DOCX file and find the file \word\styles.xml that retains this language in the following tag (indented):

```
    <w:docDefaults>
        <w:rPrDefault>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:asciiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:eastAsiaTheme="minorHAnsi" w:hAnsiTheme="minorHAnsi" w:cstheme="minorBidi"/>
                <w:sz w:val="22"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="22"/>
                <w:lang w:val="hu-HU" w:eastAsia="en-US" w:bidi="ar-SA"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:rPrDefault>
        <w:pPrDefault>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:spacing w:after="160" w:line="259" w:lineRule="auto"/>
            </w:pPr>
        </w:pPrDefault>
    </w:docDefaults>
```

I can change this to read `en-US` instead of `hu-HU`, and that would solve this issue, however, I would prefer to use Word interface, to change this. I also see that there is a style called "Default Paragraph Font", but this cannot be changed.

Is it known what UI in Word this information is controlled by? Can it be changed through anything, even with either VBA or any Word API?

**Edit:** Through the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.runpropertiesdefault?view=openxml-2.8.1) I have found out, that this is indeed the default proofing language. I still have to find the specification on this.

Also, seemingly nothing can change what is the default proofing language on a new Word document, yet Word does know what language to initiate it with through the Normal.dotm file, which if is missing, it creates it with something. That language isn't the input language, the current language of Word, nor is it the System language. My assumption that this is the language Office originally installed as, and probably controlled by a registry key, but all of this is way out of scope of what I'm asking.

Comment: I remember on older versions of O365 that language packs are installed on the computer like a regular program, maybe open control panel to programs and features and see if you have a Hungarian language pack installed?

Comment: I have "Microsoft 365 en-gb" on one PC, and on the other, both "Microsoft 365 en-us" and "Microsoft 365 hu-hu" is installed. This is partly not surprising, because I have changed around the language before on the second PC, but it *is* running in Hungarian. I did not find anything else there that relates to Office.

Comment: If you select all text, go to Review -> Language -> Language -> Set proofing language and then choose English does that do anything?
And I'm assuming you can make Hungarian not the preferred language with the other option of that dropdown so this won't happen again

Comment: What that does, is change the proofing language of all the text. But after if I select a word in a sentence, and select the Strong style, the proofing language for that word that now have the Strong style, reverts to Hungarian. This happens regardless which Word version I use, once the document was created once as Hungarian, it will behave like this.

Comment: Other thing I've seen is that the default language for O365 will get set to the default language of the system. Maybe try temporarily changing your Windows default language to English and see if that fixes the reverting?

Comment: Luckily, one is already English. This does not change anything for documents already created, however, changing the input language before creating the document does seem to affect this. So, I guess I found the solution? I'll play around with this before composing an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145465/discussion-between-adam-l-s-and-justdoingmyjob).

Comment: I've gathered the followings: 0. This *is indeed* the default proofing language for all text; 1. you cannot change this default language through Word (yet); 2. a new document takes this value from your Normal.dotm file in your %APPDATA%; 3. I still don't know where the proofing language is taken from, but it isn't the input language, nor Word's language, nor the System settings. It still could be the Office language at installation time, but I am not going to test that specifically.

Comment: Thanks, Microsoft, for making things as unintuitive and as hard as possible, just like usual. Anyways, glad you figured it out.